# Why scanf works normally when using pointer to a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm wondering why this code can work. I'm assuming that the `scanf` is assigning the value to the address of a pointer to a `char`. I know this expression is undefined but why does `printf` using a pointer can print the correct value?

```
int main() {
    char* p;
    p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    scanf("%c", &p);
    printf("%c", p);
    return 0;
}
```

And the result is

```
c
c
```

Comment: Because `printf` doesn't assign anything.

Comment: "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get compiler warnings. If not, you should consider using `-Wall`.

Comment: Please choice between c and c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `scanf()`, you are storing (rather forcibly) one byte into a variable that is more than one byte (`sizeof(char *)`, likely 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine).  With the `printf()`, you then read one byte (`sizeof(char)`, always one by standard) of this variable of size `sizeof(char *)` (more than one byte) and print it.  Your variable `p` is more space than is needed to store a `char`.  Since the sizes don't line up, you're not sure which byte of `p` will be read by `printf()`.  It could be the byte that `scanf()` wrote, or it could be garbage data.  You just got lucky and `printf()` read the same byte that `scanf()` wrote.

If all this sounds a bit uncertain, it is because it involves undefined behaviour.  You are using `scanf()` and `printf()` improperly, so they make no guarantees as to what will happen.  In short, don't do this.

`printf()` and `scanf()` don't perform any special type checking on the source/destination given as an argument.  They use fancy pointer arithmetic with the arguments on the stack to figure out where to read/write things as needed.  After the compiler builds it, `printf()` and `scanf()` will not complain.  Your compiler should have given you warnings that the types of the arguments given do not match the format string.  If it didn't, you either have a bad/old compiler or you should enable more warnings with the command line option `-Wall`.

Comment: I know I shouldn't do this, I'm just wondering why this code works.

Comment: I tried to explain it in this answer: you store data in something bigger than needed, then read something from the same container. You got lucky that what came out was what you expected. Technically, **it doesn't work**. You just happened to observe the same outcome that would have happened if it did work.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is a variable that holds a memory address, and memory addresses are surely longer than 1 byte. If you store a char value in this variable, the previous value (the malloc'ed memory block) will be lost. `printf` just treates your variable as a `char` variable and prints its contents. If you suspected that the char would be stored in the memory block obtained by malloc, no it wasn't.

Try this:

```
int main() {
    char *p, *q;
    p = q = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    scanf("%c", &p);
    printf("%c\n%c\n", p, *q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The fact that the `malloc()`'d memory is not used is a good point. What `scanf()` stores it is storing in the local variable `p`, which resides on the stack.

Comment: So even if type are different, it might also print the right value?

Answer (score 0):

To hopefully help explain the other answers, it looks as if you were aiming to do the following - compare the differences then take another look at the other answers and see if that helps, as I'm not sure you're yet clear about what's happening in your code.

```
int main() {
    char* p = malloc(sizeof(char));
    scanf("%c", p);
    printf("%c", *p);
    return 0;
}
```